Unable to solve a logarithmic equation
I'm trying to solve this logarithmic equation for a while now, but I'm not getting any concrete solution.
$\log_{3x+8}(x^2 + 8x + 16) + \log_{x+4}(3x^2 + 20x + 32) = 7$
I defined the domain, converted to factors, applied the logarithmic rules, but I'm stil unable to solve it.
Domain: $x∈\left(-\frac{8}{3}, -\frac{7}{3}\right) ∪ \left(-\frac{7}{3}, +∞\right)$
Factoring:
$\log_{3x+8}(x + 4)^2 + \log_{x+4}((3x + 8)(x + 4)) = 7$
Decomposition:
$2 \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) + \log_{x+4}(3x + 8) + \log_{x+4}(x + 4) = 7$
After subtraction:
$2 \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) + \log_{x+4}(3x + 8) = 6$
What now?
Any help would be appreciated! 

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax to typeset the equation

Welcome to math stack exchange. A couple of ways to improve your post (and likely get a better response): (1) Put your question directly into the post, using Mathjax. (2) Show specifically what you tried, rather than a general description of what you tried.

@AlainRemillard Thanks! Updated just now.

@paw88789 Sure! Thanks for the info

Given:
$$ \log_{3x+8}(x^2 + 8x + 16) + \log_{x+4}(3x^2 + 20x + 32) = 7 $$
$$ \log_{3x+8}((x + 4)^2) + \log_{x+4}((3x + 8)(x + 4)) = 7 $$
$$ 2 \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) + \log_{x+4}(3x + 8) + \log_{x+4}(x + 4) = 7 $$
$$ 2 \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) + \log_{x+4}(3x + 8) = 6 $$
Let $ \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) = a $ and by change of base formula $ \log_{x+4}(3x + 8) = \frac{1}{a} $
The equation becomes
$$ 2a + \frac{1}{a} = 6 $$
$$ 2a^2 - 6a + 1 = 0 $$
$$ a = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{7}}{2} $$
$$ \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) = \frac{3 + \sqrt{7}}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad \log_{3x+8}(x + 4) = \frac{3 - \sqrt{7}}{2} $$
Solving numerically you get $x\approx  -2.26117 $

Cool. Thank you so much. How did you solve this numerically tho?

enchanted silicon runes

Bahahaha, makes sense
